# Object containing vector of pointers of another object

Tags: c++, oop

I know I can't have the connection vector because it contains an object that doesn't exist yet at that line of code. I can't switch the order because Vertex doesn't exist yet.

```
struct Vertex {
    int key;
    int val;
    vector<Edge*> connections;
    Vertex(int k) {
        key = k;
    }

};


struct Edge {
    Vertex *start;
    Vertex *end;
    int weight;
    Edge(Vertex *s, Vertex *e, int w) {
        start = s;
        end = e;
        weight = w;
    }
};
```

So my solution to this is create a new object and placing connections in there.

```
struct Node {
    int key;
    int val;
    Node(int k) {
        key = k;
    }

};


struct Edge {
    Node *start;
    Node *end;
    int weight;
    Edge(Node *s, Node *e, int w) {
        start = s;
        end = e;
        weight = w;
    }
};

struct Vertex {
    Node node;
    vector<Edge*> connections;
};
```

Is there a better alternative where I only need to keep two objects instead of three?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to forward-declare `Edge`:

```
struct Edge;

struct Vertex {
    int key;
    int val;
    vector<Edge*> connections;
    Vertex(int k) {
        key = k;
    }
};
```

Comment: I've come across this problem where I thought forward declaring was sufficient when storing pointers to a class in a vector, because I assumed internally std::vector just kept a pointer to it, but in my case it wouldn't let me. I don't know if it's something to do with the allocator needing to know the size of it or what.

Comment: If you forward declare a pointer or reference type used in a container or function declaration, you still need to define the type before you ever use it.  So it's possible this happened to you.  Or you may have fallen into the trap of having a `std::unique_ptr` class member with a forward-declared template type without explicitly defining a destructor (in that case, the destructor is defaulted, and tries to invoke `delete` on the forward-declared type).